I'm facing error when i'm trying to create a parameter in superset
when I am filtering the data from a column in superset dashboard, i'm facing the following error, can some one please help on how to create a parameter based on ID column.
Oops! An error occurred!
Error: Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7Bs%2C%20e%2C%20c%7D&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
How to add a parameter or control values to superset dashboard.
